# Cloud Migration from AWS to GCP using Velostrata

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

During the VM Migration from AWS to GCP Cloud, the process is failing with the error:

> Finished job: StartFullMigration on VM: i-0240124484b1xxxxx, result: Failed, reason: [Connecting to Importer. Failed to upload and decompress file] (Sub-task failed)
>
> Exception:
>   com.velostrata.management.automation.exceptions.FailFlowException: [Connecting to Importer. Failed to upload and decompress file] (Sub-task failed)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.flows.FlowBase.isDone(FlowBase.java:74)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.flows.StartFullMigration.lambda$isDone$1(StartFullMigration.java:102)
>      at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.flows.StartFullMigration.isDone(StartFullMigration.java:102)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.VmWorkerImpl.monitor(VmWorkerImpl.java:126)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.VmWorkerImpl.runFlow(VmWorkerImpl.java:88)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.VmWorkerImpl.safeRunFlow(VmWorkerImpl.java:74)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.VmWorkerImpl.iterate(VmWorkerImpl.java:69)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.GroupWorkerImpl.lambda$run$3(GroupWorkerImpl.java:70)
>      at com.velostrata.automation.infra.utils.Wait.till(Wait.java:40)
>      at com.velostrata.automation.infra.utils.Wait.till(Wait.java:87)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.GroupWorkerImpl.run(GroupWorkerImpl.java:57)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.JobsRunnerImpl.runGroup(JobsRunnerImpl.java:88)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.JobsRunnerImpl.runPartOfJob(JobsRunnerImpl.java:80)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.JobsRunnerImpl.run(JobsRunnerImpl.java:72)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.JobsRunnerImpl.start(JobsRunnerImpl.java:48)
>      at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.RunsManagerImpl$RunFutureTask.lambda$new$0(RunsManagerImpl.java:246)
>      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

From the error it seems to be some kind to network issue , but I am unable to figure it out at which cloud its failing and what need to be done to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the problem that was causing this error for us recently, was that our route tables were not propagated. 
In AWS, go to the VPC dashboard > route tables > select the route table specific to the connection (which subnet?) you are trying to make > Route Propagation > edit route propagation > and check "yes". Save, close, and fire off your migration.

If that doesn't quite do the trick, check and double check your firewall rules and security group ingress rules. You may need other things open, but I had to open 443 on AWS to the specific subnets I was working with. We also have 80, 3389 for RDP, and then we opened ICMP so we could try pinging one cloud from the other. The GCP side is more extensive, but we just used the recommended firewall rules - and the fw-workload, fw-velostrata, and fw-velosmanager network tags. We also have a VPN we had to double and triple check. Any mismatches there could cause the same error.